# cannot load localhost in browser - xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

When i try to load localhost in any browser, it just keeps on loading for 10 ish minutes, before it times out. I have had this problem before, but then i just changed port 80 to 8080 or something alike, and unticked the option in skype settings.

This time it didnt cut it for me. I seriously have no clue how to fix this problem. Please let me know, if i can provide you with anymore information.

Apache error log:

```
[Fri Nov 22 16:02:38.463474 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 6212:tid 272] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Nov 22 16:02:38.910499 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 6212:tid 272] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Nov 22 16:02:38.959502 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6212:tid 272] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 22 16:02:38.959502 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6212:tid 272] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34
[Fri Nov 22 16:02:38.959502 2013] [core:notice] [pid 6212:tid 272] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Nov 22 16:02:38.960502 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6212:tid 272] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3740
Apache server shutdown initiated...
sl:warn] [pid 3740:tid 284] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Nov 22 16:02:40.097567 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 3740:tid 284] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Nov 22 16:02:40.131569 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3740:tid 284] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Fri Nov 22 16:02:40.136569 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 3740:tid 1812] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Fri Nov 22 16:02:40.136569 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 3740:tid 1800] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Fri Nov 22 16:02:40.136569 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 3740:tid 1804] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Fri Nov 22 16:02:40.136569 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 3740:tid 1824] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Fri Nov 22 20:01:07.318893 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6212:tid 272] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Fri Nov 22 20:01:09.320008 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3740:tid 284] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Nov 22 20:01:09.351010 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6212:tid 272] AH00430: Parent: Child process 3740 exited successfully.
[Tue Nov 26 10:01:15.190414 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 6744:tid 272] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:01:15.668441 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 6744:tid 272] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:01:15.746446 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6744:tid 272] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 26 10:01:15.747446 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6744:tid 272] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34
[Tue Nov 26 10:01:15.747446 2013] [core:notice] [pid 6744:tid 272] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Nov 26 10:01:15.748446 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6744:tid 272] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4900
[Tue Nov 26 10:01:16.362481 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4900:tid 284] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:01:16.809506 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4900:tid 284] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:01:16.841508 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4900:tid 284] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Nov 26 10:01:16.845508 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 4900:tid 1808] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:01:16.845508 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 4900:tid 1832] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:01:16.845508 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 4900:tid 1820] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:01:16.845508 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 4900:tid 1800] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:14:57.341438 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 1104:tid 272] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:14:57.363439 2013] [core:warn] [pid 1104:tid 272] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Tue Nov 26 10:14:57.754462 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 1104:tid 272] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:14:57.786464 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1104:tid 272] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 26 10:14:57.786464 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1104:tid 272] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34
[Tue Nov 26 10:14:57.786464 2013] [core:notice] [pid 1104:tid 272] AH00094: Command line: 'apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Nov 26 10:14:57.787464 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1104:tid 272] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4852
Apache server shutdown initiated...
sl:warn] [pid 4852:tid 284] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:14:58.872526 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4852:tid 284] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:14:58.911528 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4852:tid 284] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Nov 26 10:14:58.916528 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 4852:tid 1816] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:14:58.916528 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 4852:tid 1812] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:14:58.916528 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 4852:tid 1828] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:14:58.916528 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 4852:tid 1820] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:15:02.393727 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1104:tid 272] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Nov 26 10:15:04.394841 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4852:tid 284] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Nov 26 10:15:04.421843 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1104:tid 272] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4852 exited successfully.
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:00.240354 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 6792:tid 272] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:00.692380 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 6792:tid 272] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:00.724381 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6792:tid 272] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:00.724381 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6792:tid 272] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:00.724381 2013] [core:notice] [pid 6792:tid 272] AH00094: Command line: 'apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:00.725381 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6792:tid 272] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4900
Apache server shutdown initiated...
sl:warn] [pid 4900:tid 284] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:01.819444 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4900:tid 284] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:01.850446 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4900:tid 284] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:01.854446 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 4900:tid 1820] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:01.854446 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 4900:tid 1812] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:01.854446 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 4900:tid 1828] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:01.854446 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 4900:tid 1808] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:16.033257 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6792:tid 272] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:18.034371 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4900:tid 284] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:18.060373 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6792:tid 272] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4900 exited successfully.
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:31.067117 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 5684:tid 272] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:31.498142 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 5684:tid 272] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:31.530143 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5684:tid 272] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:31.530143 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5684:tid 272] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:31.530143 2013] [core:notice] [pid 5684:tid 272] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:31.531143 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5684:tid 272] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5544
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:32.134178 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 5544:tid 284] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:32.597204 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 5544:tid 284] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:32.628206 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5544:tid 284] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:32.631206 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 5544:tid 1820] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:32.631206 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 5544:tid 1812] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:32.631206 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 5544:tid 1828] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Tue Nov 26 10:26:32.631206 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 5544:tid 1824] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
```

Netstat -ao :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Teilmann>netstat -ao

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       2968
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       828
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       2448
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:554            Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       4588
  TCP    0.0.0.0:563            Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       2448
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2869           Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       3780
  TCP    0.0.0.0:4433           Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       2968
  TCP    0.0.0.0:10243          Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:17500          Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       3428
  TCP    0.0.0.0:17729          Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       1964
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       492
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       892
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       968
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49156          Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       556
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49157          Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       576
  TCP    0.0.0.0:57837          Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       2448
  TCP    25.196.97.39:139       Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       4
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           Teilmann-PC:50016      CLOSE_WAIT      2968
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           Teilmann-PC:50017      CLOSE_WAIT      2968
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           Teilmann-PC:50543      CLOSE_WAIT      2968
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           Teilmann-PC:50544      CLOSE_WAIT      2968
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           Teilmann-PC:50546      CLOSE_WAIT      2968
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           Teilmann-PC:50547      CLOSE_WAIT      2968
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           Teilmann-PC:50560      CLOSE_WAIT      2968
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           Teilmann-PC:50561      CLOSE_WAIT      2968
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           Teilmann-PC:50630      ESTABLISHED     2968
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           Teilmann-PC:50631      CLOSE_WAIT      2968
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4370         Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       3096
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4380         Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       3096
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       1888
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5939         Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       2124
  TCP    127.0.0.1:11000        Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       3552
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12000        Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       3552
  TCP    127.0.0.1:19872        Teilmann-PC:49190      ESTABLISHED     3428
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49155        Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       1052
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49162        Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       3552
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49167        Teilmann-PC:49168      ESTABLISHED     2448
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49168        Teilmann-PC:49167      ESTABLISHED     2448
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49169        Teilmann-PC:49170      ESTABLISHED     2448
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49170        Teilmann-PC:49169      ESTABLISHED     2448
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49171        Teilmann-PC:49172      ESTABLISHED     2448
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49172        Teilmann-PC:49171      ESTABLISHED     2448
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49173        Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       3544
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49175        Teilmann-PC:49176      ESTABLISHED     2448
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49176        Teilmann-PC:49175      ESTABLISHED     2448
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49178        Teilmann-PC:49179      ESTABLISHED     2448
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49179        Teilmann-PC:49178      ESTABLISHED     2448
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49190        Teilmann-PC:19872      ESTABLISHED     3428
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50016        Teilmann-PC:http       FIN_WAIT_2      3652
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50017        Teilmann-PC:http       FIN_WAIT_2      3652
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50543        Teilmann-PC:http       FIN_WAIT_2      3652
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50544        Teilmann-PC:http       FIN_WAIT_2      3652
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50546        Teilmann-PC:http       FIN_WAIT_2      3652
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50547        Teilmann-PC:http       FIN_WAIT_2      3652
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50560        Teilmann-PC:http       FIN_WAIT_2      3652
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50561        Teilmann-PC:http       FIN_WAIT_2      3652
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50630        Teilmann-PC:http       ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50631        Teilmann-PC:http       FIN_WAIT_2      3652
  TCP    127.0.0.1:60524        Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       2448
  TCP    192.168.2.2:139        Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       4
  TCP    192.168.2.2:49164      80-239-178-216:http    CLOSE_WAIT      3552
  TCP    192.168.2.2:49186      80-239-247-208:http    CLOSE_WAIT      4004
  TCP    192.168.2.2:49197      snt-re2-7b:http        ESTABLISHED     3428
  TCP    192.168.2.2:49253      fa-in-f94:https        ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:49262      62.116.207.42:https    ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:49265      62.116.207.48:https    ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:49451      5.56.153.177:http      ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:49955      a23-53-32-60:https     CLOSE_WAIT      6812
  TCP    192.168.2.2:49956      80-239-178-203:http    CLOSE_WAIT      6812
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50442      fa-in-f94:http         ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50443      fa-in-f105:http        ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50624      80-239-178-154:https   ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50625      80-239-178-154:https   ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50626      80-239-178-154:https   ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50627      80-239-178-154:https   ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50628      80-239-178-154:https   ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50629      80-239-178-154:https   ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50648      80-239-247-145:http    ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50680      80-239-247-184:http    ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50734      arn06s02-in-f21:https  ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50741      arn06s02-in-f11:https  ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50742      fa-in-f105:https       ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50743      arn06s02-in-f15:https  ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50746      arn02s06-in-f15:https  ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50747      arn02s05-in-f29:https  ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50755      scl03s05-in-f15:https  ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50759      arn02s06-in-f11:https  ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50883      ec2-54-228-198-107:https  ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50889      stackoverflow:http     ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50890      ec2-54-243-128-120:http  ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50891      62.116.207.53:https    ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50892      stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    192.168.2.2:50893      62.116.207.59:http     ESTABLISHED     3652
  TCP    [::]:80                Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       2968
  TCP    [::]:135               Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       828
  TCP    [::]:445               Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:554               Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       4588
  TCP    [::]:2869              Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:4433              Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       2968
  TCP    [::]:10243             Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:49152             Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       492
  TCP    [::]:49153             Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       892
  TCP    [::]:49154             Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       968
  TCP    [::]:49156             Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       556
  TCP    [::]:49157             Teilmann-PC:0          LISTENING       576
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5004           *:*                                    4588
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5005           *:*                                    4588
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*                                    1136
  UDP    0.0.0.0:17500          *:*                                    3428
  UDP    0.0.0.0:55816          *:*                                    1888
  UDP    0.0.0.0:57837          *:*                                    2448
  UDP    25.196.97.39:137       *:*                                    4
  UDP    25.196.97.39:138       *:*                                    4
  UDP    25.196.97.39:1900      *:*                                    3452
  UDP    25.196.97.39:5353      *:*                                    1888
  UDP    25.196.97.39:57664     *:*                                    3452
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                                    3452
  UDP    127.0.0.1:44301        *:*                                    1124
  UDP    127.0.0.1:54382        *:*                                    3228
  UDP    127.0.0.1:57659        *:*                                    1756
  UDP    127.0.0.1:57665        *:*                                    3452
  UDP    127.0.0.1:61696        *:*                                    3544
  UDP    192.168.2.2:137        *:*                                    4
  UDP    192.168.2.2:138        *:*                                    4
  UDP    192.168.2.2:1900       *:*                                    3452
  UDP    192.168.2.2:5353       *:*                                    1888
  UDP    192.168.2.2:57663      *:*                                    3452
  UDP    [::]:5004              *:*                                    4588
  UDP    [::]:5005              *:*                                    4588
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*                                    1136
  UDP    [::]:55817             *:*                                    1888
  UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*                                    3452
  UDP    [::1]:5353             *:*                                    1888
  UDP    [::1]:57662            *:*                                    3452
  UDP    [fe80::3c18:a750:2ed3:bee%12]:1900  *:*                                    3452
  UDP    [fe80::3c18:a750:2ed3:bee%12]:57661  *:*                                    3452
  UDP    [fe80::7833:3faa:25a4:180%11]:1900  *:*                                    3452
  UDP    [fe80::7833:3faa:25a4:180%11]:57660  *:*                                    3452
```

Comment: Check for anyother service running on port 80 **Start -> Run, type in services.msc, click OK.**

Comment: How can i see in there, what ports they run on ?

Comment: Check for apache service?

Comment: There is no apache service running.

Comment: Is IIS running on your system? If so stop it by Start -> Run, type in netmgr, click OK

Comment: No its not running :)

Comment: Hey Thomas check out the below answer? Hope it will help you!

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann Did you add virtual hosts on your httpd-vhosts.conf?

Answer (score 1):

**Check What’s Using Port 80?**

Further detective work is necessary if IIS, SSRS and Skype are not to blame. Enter the following on the command line:

```
netstat -ao
```

The active TCP addresses and ports will be listed — locate the line with local address “0.0.0.0:80″ and note the PID value.

Now right-click the task bar and select Start Task Manager. Navigate to the Processes tab and, if necessary, click View > Select Columns… to ensure “PID (Process Identifier)” is checked. You can now locate the PID you noted above. The description and properties should help you determine which application is using the port.

The Task Manager allows you to kill the process, but be a little wary about doing that — especially if it’s “NT Kernel & System”.

**Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0**

NT Kernel & System is an essential service. Stopping it will probably stop Windows in a blue-screeny-like way. Therefore, enter the following at the command line:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 80
```

If you’re faced with a blank screen, type “GET” and hit return. The chances are, you’ll see a line stating that Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 is listening on port 80. If that’s the case, open Services from Administrative Tools and locate “Web Deployment Agent Service”. Stop the service and set it’s startup type to “Manual”.

The Web Deployment Agent Service is deployed with WebMatrix and was the cause of my woes. It may also be distributed with other applications installed using Microsoft’s Web Platform Installer.

That caused me a few frustrating hours so I hope it solves your Apache or WAMP start-up problems.

**Skype**

There is one more, maybe stupid but still a reason – Skype.
there is a checkbox in

```
Options->Advanced->Connection->“use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections”
```

Comment: i have httpd.exe running on port 80 atm.

Comment: I dont have the NT Kernel & system running on port 80 :/

Comment: And skype box is unticked

Comment: Try **telnet 127.0.0.1 80**, type **GET** and hit return.

Comment: "'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: I enabled telnet and yes, my CMD window is blank. Nothing happens when it type GET and hit return

Comment: I just saw that i have a program, Pando media booster, which uses up port 443. I changed apache to use 4433, but still no cigar. Seems there is more problems