# XAMPP - cannot browse localhost

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost, telnet

I am having trouble with my xampp setup. Managed successfully to install apache and sql services but still I cannot browse localhost using either chrome, firefox or IE.

Actually I get the same error log with this guy here:
[cannot load localhost in browser - xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213147/cannot-load-localhost-in-browser-xampp)

with the exception that when I try the following command "**telnet 127.0.0.1 8888**" (8888 is the port I use for apache) and then press GET and return I get this message:

`<br />`
   `<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in <b>C:xampp\htdocs\index.php`
`</b> on line <b>7</b><br />`

`Connection to host lost.`

`C:\Users\xxxx>`

Any idea how to fix this?
I am using windows 8.1 by the way.

Comment: Can you read a static HTML page?

Comment: Get Contents of index.php file, there could be variables unset and you are trying to use it. Also check httpd.conf and listen on port and make virtual part set like virtualhost 8888.*

Comment: -I think I can't, but I am not sure.
-httpd.conf is listening to the correct ports. What do you mean in the first sentence?

Comment: PS: I also get the error mentioned above in the php_error_log:
[02-Feb-2014 18:47:11 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do a clean install (disabling firewall, antivirus) and now it works as it should!